# Node.js and PHP session sharing

Tags: php, node.js, session

I am trying to share session information between our main PHP app and node.js

We currently use a database backend for session storage, because we have several web servers that can handle a request.

Is anyone aware of any solutions for accessing session data from node.js? The only ones I can see use redis or memcache, but we cannot change the method for storing session data.

Comment: If you can't change the method, then surely your only option is to retrieve the session data from the database and parse it in Node?

Comment: Yes, I could write that, I just was wondering if someone has done it before.

Answer (score 2):

You would have to use a common format, such as JSON or one of your own invention.  Let's assume JSON for convenience.

On the PHP side you will need to [register your own session handler](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php).

Set [session.name](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.name) to something less PHP specific, for example SESSID instead of PHPSESSID.

Set [session.serialize_handler](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.serialize-handler) to *php_serialize*.  In the **write()** method cast the incoming $data into JSON by first calling [unserialize()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) on it, then calling [json_encode()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) and set the re-encoded data in your database.

Similarly, the **read()** method should extract the session data from your database (given the value of the ID stored in the SESSID cookie), call [json_decode()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) on it, then [serialize](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) it and return that string.

Might I suggest a *fast*, *scalable*, and *reliable* database such as [Aerospike](http://www.aerospike.com/).  I am, however, biased.